# Reattach closed stdin of a process to bash

Tags: bash, xubuntu, 19.04, process

I was web-surfing when I accidentally closed the terminal where the command `apt full-upgrade` was running.
It was at the point when it was tellin me to stop `xlockmore` and `xscreensaver` and waiting me to click on the "ok" button when i closed the terminal's window.

At that point the process didn't exited, and now i cant complete the installation (that's what i'm hoping to do) nor safely shutdown  the pc.

I thought that **reattaching** `stdin` to a new terminal instance would be the solution to continue. What do you think? And HOW do i do it?

Suggestion are welcome, i'll wait you here with my pc on...

---

**Other details**

`Xubuntu`, using `Qterminal`, the ubuntu release is `19.04` and i was trying to upgrade to `20` with *spryfigure*'s reply:

> https://www.reddit.com/r/Lubuntu/comments/g3390k/1904_the_repository_standard_repo_no_longer_has_a/

because my pc has been inactive for a couple of months and `apt-get` update wasn't working.

Huge thanks everyone!

---

**Edit 1**
I repeated the command, but it tells that cant take the lock on `/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend` because the resource can be temporarily unavailable

**Edit 2**
The apt process is still running, i dont know how to connect to its stdin that results closed. (i was not sure that force close will not make troubles)

Comment: Generally unnecessary for the step apt was paused at. Simply re-run `sudo apt full-upgrade`.

Comment: i did it already, and it respond that apt cant take the lock so it cant continue

Comment: The lockfile ensures that only one package manager can run at a time. Since you killed the package manager, it cannot remove the lockfile. Therefore you must: `sudo apt rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend`. Removing a lockfile is only appropriate when you KNOW that a package manager is not running - running multiple package managers at once can seriously damage your system.

Comment: thanks, i just added **Edit 2** to reply to you, saying that i have the process running, i can see it with htop